# Fabricjs corner selected

Tags: fabricjs

[image]

When I move the mouse over the red circled area and click, I expect the corner to be selected,So, what's the Api can help me?

Can someone help me? My English is not very good, if you want to know more details about this problem, you can leave a message to me, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, it's always helpful to include a Minimum Reproducible Example (MRE) so that others can easily understand and reproduce the issue you're experiencing. Here is an example https://codepen.io/ad121/pen/rNZdJNr

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I create a codepen example, https://codepen.io/makerhou/pen/eYLrOrb,If I want to adjust the mtr point, I need to move the mouse to the circle of the control point corner in the figure to adjust, so that the figure will be dragged unintentionally, which is not ideal, so I need to set some around the control point Buffer area, when the mouse enters the buffer area and performs a drag operation, only adjust the position of the joint point of the polygon